# Collect user activity statistics

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture

There is an ECM system for storing documents. The system cannot be accessed outside the customer's local network. We need to collect statistics on which pages are visited most often, how many people use mobile phones to access, which buttons are most often pressed, which features are used, etc. The system is deployed on WildFly and written using JSF.

There is an idea to use Kafka to collect such statistics. I see two options to send statistics to Kafka.

**Option 1:**
Send message to Kafka when user clicks on the button or requests a page in the JavaScript code.
(Is it secure to post message from JS to Kafka? As far as I understand, in this case there is no authentication, which means it is not secure. The user can abuse the system and cheat statistics)

**Option 2:**
Send message to Kafka when user clicks on the button or requests a page in Java code. There are almost no actions in the system that occur only in the browser, almost all actions go through the backend.
(In this case, there is authentication because the user is logged into the system. However, the request takes time on the server, and in the case of sending via JS, it does not (asynchronous request))

How is it customary to collect such statistics? Using the first or second method?

Scheme: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjF86.png

Comment: JS cannot post to Kafka. You'd need to use HTTP requests to a backend server, then forward those to Kafka.

Comment: @OneCricketeer , Oh ok, got it. I just saw articles that it's possible to post messages from node.js.

Comment: I meant from client-side JS (where you would be collecting click events), but regarding click event collection, take a look at https://divolte.io/